# 'Age' is Skipping It's Property

Tags: c#

```
//File Main.cs

using BasicClasses;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Profile p = new Profile("16");
      p.PrintProfile();
    }
    }
}

//File Profile.cs

namespace BasicClasses
{
    class Profile
    {
//Fields
      public string age;

//Constructors
      public Profile(string age)
      {
        this.age = age;
      }

//Properties
      private string Age
      { get { return this.age; }
        set 
        {
          if (value.Length > 0)
          {
            if (Int32.Parse(value) >= 18)
            { Age = value; }

            else
            { Age = "Invalid Age"; }
          }
          else
          { Age = "Not Defined"; }
        }
      }

//Methods
      public void PrintProfile()
      {
        Console.WriteLine($"Age :: {Age}");
      }

    }
}

//Output
//Age :: 16
```

My issue is with the variable 'Age'. The output should be "Age :: Invalid Age". I defined 'this.age' in a constructor and used that variable in the property of 'Age'. However the property is outputting the exact same thing that was entered in the constructor seemingly Skipping the Property of 'Age'.

Comment: You are effectively creating an infinite loop in your setter. If the value being assigned to the `Age` property is invalid, you set the `Age` property to `"Invalid Age"`, which is not a valid age and therefore it sets itself to `"Invalid Age"`, etc etc. Use the `age` field as a backing field. Set that instead of your `Age` property. Read more about properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Comment: you are printning the private variable Age but setting the public age (small a) in the constructor

Comment: A guess a JavaScript programmer can write JavaScript programs in any language. This is really bad design overall.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems.

1 - Its attribution in the constructor, by directly calling its field "this.age", does not pass through the validation created in its property.

```
public Profile(string age)
{
    this.Age = age;
}
```

2 - Your validation will return an Exception, because when parsing the value "Invalid Age" you will get an error. You should set the Field value to avoid this:

```
private string Age
{
   get { return this.age; }
   set
   {
       if (value.Length > 0)
       {
           if (Int32.Parse(value) >= 18)
           { this.age = value; }
           else
           { this.age = "Invalid Age"; }
       }
       else
       { this.age = "Not Defined"; }
    }
}
```

Another piece of advice I would give you would be to change your validation to:

```
if (int.TryParse(value, out var integerValue) && integerValue >= 18)
{ this.age = integerValue.ToString(); }
```

Thus avoiding a possible exception.
Hope I helped, have a good journey.